# finding a string given a directory, extension, and string?

Tags: python, directory

Currently, I'm trying to determine how to return a list of filenames in the directory containing a particular string...
here's how i began:

```
def searchABatch(directory, extension, searchString):
     for file in os.listdir(directory):
         if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, extension):
             return file

print(searchABatch("procedural", ".py", "foil"))
```

I expected it to print simply the files with the extension ".py" in my "procedural" directory but I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pitcher20aLP2.py", line 38, in <module>
    print(searchABatch("procedural", ".py", "foil")) 
  File "pitcher20aLP2.py", line 34, in searchABatch
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'procedural'
```

Comment: Maybe your current working directory isn't what you think it is. Try `print(os.getcwd())` to confirm that you're in the right place.

Comment: /home/2020/pitcher20a/procedural i get this so i believe im in the correct directory

Comment: Im thinking that it just needs to be a path... But im not quire sure how to make a directory into "path format"

Comment: If `os.getcwd()` returns `/home/2020/pitcher20a/procedural`, that might be a problem. `os.listdir()` is looking in your current directory for a folder named "procedural", but you're already in a folder named procedural. Unless your procedural folder has a second folder named procedural inside it, `os.listdir` isn't going to find it. Try using `os.listdir(".")` to iterate through the contents of the current directory.

Comment: OHHHH!!!!!!! I SEE! Okay, thank you so much, i understand it now :))))

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to print contents of directory that doesn't exist in you current working directory. You should check if provided `directory` is actually a directory before calling `os.listdir()`, by using [`os.path.isdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html?highlight=exp#os.path.isdir)

```
def searchABatch(directory, extension, searchString):
    if os.path.isdir(directory):
        for file in os.listdir(directory):
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, extension):
                return file

print(searchABatch("procedural", ".py", "foil"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Kevin is right, you are trying to find `procedural` in `/home/2020/pitcher20a/procedural` directory.

Check your working directory with `os.getcwd()` and change it needed by using `os.chdir(path)`. Also, you can check if the directory is even a directory by using `os.path.isdir()` before using `os.listdir()`.

Here is the python os module documentation - https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

Also, try to handle the errors gracefully.